# how to draw line on glasspane?

Tags: java, swing, glasspane

Please can anyone help me on this. I have this jtable and I want to draw a line on it in any directions. I've also read about glasspane which  made it possilbe but I couldn't manage to do it. Can anyone give me example on this. PS. I use extended JFrame in class thank you.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)  I mean *besides* asking random strangers on the internet to do it for you.

Answer (score 4):

1. Create own component class (extend `JComponent`).
2. Override `paintComponent()` and draw whatever you need.
3. Set instance of your component as glass pane in your frame.

[How to Use Root Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) tutorial from Oracle provides clear [example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/GlassPaneDemoProject/src/components/GlassPaneDemo.java).